# Fire event when $emit is complete

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent component that has a child component in it. When a button is clicked in the child, it emits back to the parent:

```
   clickevent(data){
            this.$emit('back-to-parent', data);

  }
```

My dilemma is i need to know when emit is finished so i can execute code thats dependent upon it. I tried this:

```
        clickevent(data){
           this.$emit('back-to-parent', {data, done: () => { 
                 alert('done') 
             } });
       }
```

But my alert never fires. I tried these but they dont work https://forum.vuejs.org/t/do-something-after-emit-has-finished-successful/10663

How do i execute code after my emit is finished? Thanks

Comment: you should call `done` callback manually after a parent component is done with emitted event

Comment: i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Did you try the nextTick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in a parent component:

```
@back-to-parent="onBackToParent"
...
methods: {
  onBackToParent({ data, done }) {
    // process data
    if (done) {
      done()
    }
  }
}
```

in a child component:

```
clickevent(data){
           this.$emit('back-to-parent', {data, done: () => { 
                 alert('done') 
             } });
       }
```

Comment: YES! This is exacty what i wanted. Thank you

Comment: THANK YOU! I have looked everywhere for this.

Comment: useful answer - seems like the best we can do, but it means more boilerplate code for the caller. It would be better if there could be something to detect when the emit finishes. Maybe this need is a code smell that the structure of our code itself is lacking, or maybe this is just lacking in VueJS. It would be nice if emit were a promise the way setting a vuex proxies are.